# Regular expression fun with emails; top level domain not required when it should be

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expressions that will filter valid emails using PHP and have ran into an issue that conflicts with what I understand of regular expressions. Here is the code that I am using.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $string)) {
return $false;
}
```

Now from the materials that I've researched, this should allow content before the @ to be multiple letters, numbers, underscores and periods, then afterwards to allow multiple letters and numbers, then require a period, then two to four letters for the top level domain.

However, right now it ignores the requirement for having the top level domain section. For example a@b.c obviously is valid (and should be), but a@b is also returning as valid, which I want ti to be flagged as not so.

I'm sure I"m missing something, but after browsing google for an hour I'm at a loss as to what it could be. Anyone have an answer for this conundrum?

EDIT: The speed that answers arrive here makes this site superior over it's competitors. Well done!

Comment: Your regular expression does not match a@b.c.d.

Comment: Is it supposed to match any email address, meaning just check if it's a valid one? Check out PHP's own filter_var method using the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL constant. Might do the trick just fine..

Comment: Ya I think I might just use it. This isn't behaving as I've been told through multiple sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should escape `.` when it's not a part of the group: `'/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/'`
Otherwise it will be equal to any letter:

- `.` - any symbol (but not the newline `\n` if not using [`s` modifier](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlre.html))
- `\.` - dot symbol
- `[.]` - dot symbol (inside symbol group)

Comment: Instead of \., I find [.] to be more readable. It puts the . character into its own group.

Comment: Agreed. Although it didnt' make a difference. Both \. and [.] still say that the email passed is valid.

Comment: I've just executed `var_dump(preg_match('/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', 'a@basd'));` and it prints `int(0)` which is false

Comment: Yep I found the mistake on my end. My apologies for the erroneous reply earlier.

Comment: john@some.domain.co.uk or john@example.co.uk won't validate with that regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than rolling your own, perhaps you should read the article [How to Find or Validate an Email Address on Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). The article also discusses reasons why you might not want to validate an email address using a regular expression and provides 3 regular expressions that you might consider using instead of your own.

Answer (score 3):

From the page [Comparing E-mail Address Validating Regular Expressions](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php): Geert De Deckere from the Kohana project has developed a near perfect one:

```
/^[-_a-z0-9\'+*$^&%=~!?{}]++(?:\.[-_a-z0-9\'+*$^&%=~!?{}]+)*+@(?:(?![-.])[-a-z0-9.]+(?<![-.])\.[a-z]{2,6}|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?::\d++)?$/iD
```

But there is also a buildin function in PHP `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` but it seems to be under development. And there is an other serious solution: [PEAR:Validate](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.validate.validate.email.php). I think the PEAR Solution is the best one.

Comment: I've ran into some limitations of the filter_Var one (unlimited top domain sizes for one) so I'll give the PEAR one a shot. Thanks!

Comment: what are "unlimited top domain sizes"? It has come to my understanding that a tld can be up to 5 characters (.museum) and a domain can be up to 63 characters.

Answer (score 2):

[An RFC822-compliant e-mail regex is available](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Comment: Will this work for PHP? I ask as it looks to be a Perl module?

Comment: The Perl module just gives you an easy way of running things through that regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most reasonable trade off of the spec versus real life that I have seen:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+
(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+
(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)\b
```

Of course, you have to remove the line breaks, and you have to update it if more top-level domains become available.

Answer (score 0):

A single dot in a regular expression means "match *any* character". And that's exactly what is does when a top level domain is missing (also when it's present, of course).

Thus you should change your code like that:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $string)) {
    return $false;
}
```

And by the way: [a lot more characters are allowed in the local part](http://www.remote.org/jochen/mail/info/chars.html) than what your regular expression currently allows for.

Comment: Agreed on your link. I figured though that I should get this working before I start to get more involved and get in way over my head. 

Also tried your code. Same result, it does not require a dot and validates without it.